# Python time and date function - confused

Tags: python, date, datetime

I want to take a time stamp from the epoch - 1507498737.999 and store it as float in a nosql database. I also want to convert the epoch time to:

- Year
- Month
- Day
- Hour
- Minute
- Seconds
- Milliseconds
- DayName
- MonthName
- others?

I keep running into issues with conversions. My thought is:

- Get the now() timestamp (floating)
- Convert the timestamp to Year, Month, Day, etc...

How?

Comment: Why do you mention python ? What is your code, what did you try?

Comment: "I keep running into issues" -- what issues? Do you have some code demonstrating such an issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you create a python `datetime` object, you may access the properties you need.

```
>>> import datetime
>>> dt = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1507498737.999)
>>> print(dt)
2017-10-09 08:38:57.999000
>>> dt.microsecond
999000
>>> dt.day
9
```